# Pig ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I've two files,I am trying to join these two on the basis of pattern matching.

```
File1 :

weather.bbc.co.uk,112 
ads.facebook.com,113 
ads.amazon.co.uk,114 
www.sky.com,115 
news.bbc.co.uk,116 
pics.facebook.com,117

File2 :

facebook.com,facebook 
bbc.co.uk,bbc 
netflix.com,netflix 
flipkart.com,flipkart

output:

weather.bbc.co.uk,112,bbc.co.uk,bbc
ads.facebook.com,113,facebook.com,facebook
news.bbc.co.uk,116,bbc.co.uk,bbc
pics.facebook.com,117,facebook.com,facebook 

Script

file1 = LOAD '/file1' using PigStorage('|') as (request_domain: chararray,msisdn:int);       
file2 = LOAD '/file2' using PigStorage('|') as (domain: chararray,provider: chararray);
file3 = JOIN file1 by case when (request_domain MATCHES CONCAT(CONCAT('(?i).*',file2.domain),'.*')) then file2.domain  else 'Other' end LEFT OUTER,file2 by domain;
DESCRIBE file3;            
dump file3;
```

But I am getting an error as following :

> WARN [Thread-29] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner -
>   job_local_0006 org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException:
>   ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st :
>   (facebook.com,facebook), 2nd :(bbc.co.uk,bbc) at
>   org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.ReadScalars.exec(ReadScalars.java:111) at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNext(POUserFunc.java:330)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNextString(POUserFunc.java:432)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNext(PhysicalOperator.java:317)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.processInput(POUserFunc.java:221)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNext(POUserFunc.java:275)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNextString(POUserFunc.java:432)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNext(PhysicalOperator.java:317)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.processInput(POUserFunc.java:221)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNext(POUserFunc.java:275)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNextString(POUserFunc.java:432)

Answer (score 0):

The separate should be "," instead of "|"  -> PigStorage(',')

The pattern will match multiple values , try using cross functions with indexof udf as below

```
file1 = LOAD 'data/file1.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (request_domain: chararray,msisdn:int);       
file2 = LOAD 'data/file2.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (domain: chararray,provider: chararray);
crossed = CROSS file1,file2;
filtered = FILTER crossed BY INDEXOF(file1::request_domain,file2::domain) != -1 ;
```

Comment: what is the logic that you want in the script  ?

Comment: I want to join two dataset on the basis of pattern match.

Comment: what pattern do you want ?

Comment: output:

`weather.bbc.co.uk,112,bbc.co.uk,bbc`
`ads.facebook.com,113,facebook.com,facebook`

Comment: the pattern is incorrect as it will match multiple values eg weather.bbc.co.uk and news.bbc.co.uk hence it is failing try using cross function

Comment: actually I want all values that are matching,I've edited it in the question.Using cross is not a feasible approach if the datasets have billions of data.